# Why show Nothing data record in view AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying make an ajax request to php from angular js.
I no error and show Nothing data record in view

retrieving data from server but not Search in recordsCtrl function init().

My source:

View : jalse.html:

```
<div class="content-panel" ng-init="init()">
    <div class="content-panel-title">
        <h2> Date : {{jalse.contentDate}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>{{jalse.contentAbstract}}</h4>
        <div>
            {{jalse.contentText}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:
  recordsCtrl.js:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var recordsCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams , jasleFactory) {
        var jalseId = $routeParams.jalseId;

        jasleFactory.getJalse().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.records = data;
        }).
        error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("error occured " + error)
        });
        $scope.jalse = null;

        function init() {
            for (var i = 0, len = $scope.records.length; i < len; i++) {
                if ($scope.records[i].contentID == parseInt(jalseId)) {
                    $scope.jalse = $scope.records[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }   
    };
       recordsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams', 'jasleFactory'];
       angular.module('myApp').controller('recordsCtrl', recordsCtrl);
}());
```

Factory : 
    jalseFactory.js:

```
(function () {

    var jasleFactory = function ($http) {

        var factory = {};

        factory.getJalse = function () {
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'includes/records.php'});
        };
        return factory;
    };

    jasleFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
    angular.module('myApp').factory('jasleFactory', jasleFactory);

}());
```

File app.js:

```
 (function () {
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                controller: 'contentsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/contents.php'
            })

            .when('/jalse/:jalseId', {
                controller: 'recordsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/jalse.php'
            })

            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.

`ng-init="init()"` isn't working because the init function wasn't assigned to a scope variable such as `$scope.init=init;` so it is undefined in the view

Even if it was assigned it would run before the data has returned from server. Therefore `$scope.records` would be  undefined within `init()`.

You could remove `ng-init="init()"` and call the init() in the success callback

```
jasleFactory.getJalse().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.records = data;
    init();
}).
```

Comment: any errors in console? Is request being made and succeeding in network tab of console?

Comment: Nothing error - I print records in view But not search

Comment: well printing records is a good start. Not sure what you mean by search...nothing like that in view html shown. Sounds like a child scope issue

Comment: I solve problem after change  $scope.records = data.records;